# Why AsyncTask run twice when i try to write some data on a web server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I have this Android program that writes a data on a web DB (MySQL) in this way: AndroidApp -> HTTP GET -> PHP -> MySQL DB. On App side, i use one AsyncTask to read a form and generate the URL HTTP to send to the web server when i click on the "Save" button.

Here's the problem: when i click the "save" button on the first time, the app works fine. But when i try to insert a new value in the DB, the new value is written correctly but a second thread (like a ghost) re-writes the old one value. 
So in my DB now i have:
-DATA1 <- inserted on the first time
-DATA2 <- inserted on the second time
-DATA1 <- inserted also on the second time (this is wrong!)

I can't understand why this happends on the second time. 
Any help is appreciated. :)

The first time it works just one AsyncTask works, but the second time the AsyncTask works twice (writes the new data and the old one).

PS: Web client (HTTP GET,PHP and MySQL) all work fine. The problem is just on client Android :(

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task;
    EditText id_location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    }

    public void startButton(View view){
        id_location = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.editText1);
         task = new AsyncTaskd(this,id_location.getText().toString());
         task.execute(); 
    }
}
```

AsyncTask code:

```
public class AsyncTaskd  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    String string;
    Context context;

   public AsyncTaskd(Context context, String string) {
       this.string = string; 
       this.context = context;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute(){

   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

       android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

       try{
             String link = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/access.php?type_connection=insert"+
             "&id_location="+string;
             Log.w("DEBUG", "'"+string+"'");
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
             request.setURI(new URI(link));
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line=""; 
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line);
               break;
             }
             in.close();
             return sb.toString();
           }catch(Exception e){
              return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
           }
       }


   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    System.out.println("Insert "+ result );
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    this.cancel(true); 
   }
}
```

Comment: And the third time? This code looks ok. Please show the php.

Comment: At the third time, the app writes the new data (DATA3) and the old one (DATA2) -that is the data of the second time-.

Comment: `the app writes the new data (` ? Do you mean 'php writes....'?

Comment: Yes, you right. When the "App writes" i mean the "App starts the AsyncTask that sends the http URL to PHP with parameters, then the PHP writes to DB"

Comment: You are constantly blaming your app. Come to the point: the problem is in the php script. But as you dont publish we cannot help.

Comment: I posted the php code that inserts a record in table

Comment: Had a look at your android code again. You have statement `Log.w("DEBUG", "'"+string+"'");` to check what is posted. Very good. But did you check the log? Does it really post one DATA#? If you want to blame your app then here is your chance ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
During debug i was using the emulator, but it must have some problems with AsyncTask. Instend, when i tried with my telephone my app works happily all the time i want to add a new data to my DB. No more duplicates.

Thanks Greenapps for the help,
Bye

Answer (score 0):

Here's the php code that insert a data on a db from a URL HTTP:

```
<?php

//Credenziali accesso da php:
$mysql_host = "host";
$mysql_database = "database";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "password";

//connect to DB
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

//Type connection definition
$type_connection = $_GET['type_connection'];


/////////////////////
//Connect for INSERT
if($type_connection == "insert"){
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $id_location = $_GET['id_location'];


    $string="INSERT INTO `database`.`table` ( `id_location` ) VALUES ( '".$id_location."' );";

    mysqli_query($con,$string);


    echo "DONE INSERT!"; 

}

//Disconnect from DB
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Your php script cries for improvements. You are always connecting to the database. But you first should check your input variables. Use isset() to first check if variables exist and return with an appropriate message. Further you only echo ("DONE INSERT"). That is not enough. It schould at least be ("DONE INSERT" . $id_location). In general: echo much more to see what your script does. You posted this as an answer where you better had added a block to your post.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments, in future i will try to be precise.
For the post i made a mistake because it's the first time that i use stackoverflow.